# Are there any open source projects related to signal processing

Tags: signal-processing

I am going to make a program related to audio signal processing .
Are there any open source projects related to it?

Comment: *Mathematica* already has some built-in DSP-related functions, but still a far cry from MATLAB's offerings. Are you asking about packages for DSP?

Comment: There used to be [Mathematica DSP application](http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/Mathematica_for_signal_processing.htm), but most of that functionality are [integrated to Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AudioProcessing.html) now (not open source ofcourse  ;)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.no, I am looking for open source projects.in fact there are not many for Mathematica but more books about matlab,I am so sad to find that few to refer to.

Comment: By "packages" I meant *Mathematica* packages for extending the program's DSP know-how. It would be nice to have one that's FOS, yes…

Comment: @Nasser Is the application powerful in analyze and filter a signal

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. What does FOS mean? Can u recommend me some packages?

Comment: You can't buy the DSP app anymore. I have it since I bought it long time ago, but it does not run anymore on new versions of M. Check [this site](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~bevans/projects/symbolic/spp.html) which I think is the origin of that application from long time ago by Brian Evans.

Comment: @Nasser. Should that be out of time?? in fact , what i am going to do is to do a simple project: import an audio signal and filter it. Maybe the quality of filter counts most.

Comment: @Nasser Should that be out of time?? in fact , what i am going to do is to do a simple project: import an audio signal and filter it. Maybe the quality of filter counts most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The greatest curated organized repository of open source Wolfram Language programs for many specific subjects are Demonstrations, for example, related to your request fields:

- [Signal Processing (200 apps)](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Signal%20Processing&limit=20)
- [Image Processing](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Image%20Processing&limit=20)
- [Electrical Engineering](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Electrical%20Engineering&limit=20)
- [Electronics](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Electronics&limit=20)

Take also a look in the library:

- [Engineering > Signal Processing](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/BySubject/Engineering/SignalProcessing/)

--- there are are other related pages. also And also at the so called guid pages in docs:

- [Signal Processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SignalProcessing.html)

--- at the top of the page there you see examples:

[image]

--- there are are other related pages. Also search for Mathematica at

- [SE DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathematica).

And also so called new-in examples in V9 when SP got revamped:

- [Built-in Signal Processing](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-signal-processing/)

And of course [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing). And maybe you should not shy away from SystemModeler:

- [Library of electrical models (analog, digital, machines, multi-phase)](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Electrical.html)
- [Using Arduinos as SystemModeler Components](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/11/07/using-arduinos-as-systemmodeler-components/)